# Отслеживания изменения даты в android

Tags: android

В БД есть записи которые должны в программе изменятся в зависимости от текущей даты. То есть менять позицию в  `ExpandableListView` в зависимости от того какая сейчас дата.

Как в Android можно реализовать отслеживание изменения даты??

Answer (score 2):

В манифесте зарегистрировать broadcastReceiver

```
<receiver android:name=".TimeChangedReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_TICK" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

В коде создать класс описывающий его

```
public class TimeChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //будет вызываться каждую минуту
        //делаем проверки изменилась ли дата
        //если изменилась, то обновляем 
        //записи в бд
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я предлагаю ставить `Alarm` на следующую полночь.
Где-то, например, в `onCreate()` `MainActivity` нужно установить первый `Alarm`, вызвав следующий метод:

```
public void setAlarmAtNextMidnight(Context appContext) {
    Calendar nextMidnightCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    nextMidnightCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);
    nextMidnightCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    nextMidnightCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    nextMidnightCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) appContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.datechangeproject.MIDNIGHT_HAS_COME");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(appContext, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextMidnightCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

В манифесте регистрируем `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".DateChangeReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.datechangeproject.MIDNIGHT_HAS_COME" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Там же нужно испросить разрешения:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
```

Как можете видеть, будем ловить не только полночь, но и перезагрузку устройства, смену времени(которое ловит и смену даты). Ведь во всех этих случаях дата может смениться.
Далее создаем BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class DateChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equals("com.android.datechangeproject.MIDNIGHT_HAS_COME"))
        Log.d("TAG", "Вот и наступило завтра");

    //Вносите изменения в свою БД. Можете вначале убедиться, что смена даты действительно произошла.
    //Она ведь могла и не поменяться в случае перезагрузки устройства или смены времени.

    //Здесь устанавливаем срабатывание Alarm на следующую полночь
    new MainActivity().setAlarmAtNextMidnight(context.getApplicationContext());

}
```

}